# Remove color from an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to remove the color from the below image, due to this color I am unable to extract the text clearly from the image.

[image]

I am using the below code, but I am not getting the clear text,

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('my_file.tif')
im = im.convert('RGBA')
data = np.array(im)
# just use the rgb values for comparison
rgb = data[:,:,:3]
color = [246, 213, 139]   # Original value
black = [0,0,0, 255]
white = [255,255,255,255]
mask = np.all(rgb == color, axis = -1)
# change all pixels that match color to white
data[mask] = white

# change all pixels that don't match color to black
##data[np.logical_not(mask)] = black
new_im = Image.fromarray(data)
new_im.save('new_file.tif')
```

and

```
def black_and_white(input_image_path,
                output_image_path):
color_image = Image.open(input_image_path)
bw = color_image.convert('L')
bw.save(output_image_path)
```

Please help me with this...

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: load it in colorless mode using opencv and then might even invert it ?

Comment: "I am not getting the clear text" - what are you getting instead? What's the expected output?

Comment: Like @ForceBru said, please provide your current input and output.

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous. Which colour do you want to remove - there are at least 3 shades of blue as well as white and grey? What do you expect will be left when you remove the colour? Black? White? Grey? Transparency?

Comment: I want to remove all the color in that image, Except the text color

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to extract the quote. To do this, you can do a series of filtering operations to remove non-text contours. Once you have the processed result you can use an OCR tool such as Pytesseract for text extraction.

[image]

Result from OCR

```
On behalf of the hundreds of ACLU activists who
called on Governor Walker to veto House Bill
156, we are disappointed that he did not put
students or the Constitution first today.”
—Joshua A. Decker
Executive Director
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image and threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Connect text with a horizontal shaped kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

# Remove non-text contours using aspect ratio filtering
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    aspect = w/h
    if aspect < 3:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Invert image and OCR
result = 255 - thresh
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Your answer works for this image. But for another image, it does not work. After dilate whole data will get disappeared and the final image result is nothing (full white). I add that image to my question. Please check and suggest a dynamic solution.

Comment: It may not work with images where the text has a different color shade around it on top of a background color

Comment: Is there any way to extract the data from those images. Otherwise, give some ideas to improve the OCR accuracy of those images.

Comment: Yes its possible but the solution will not be dynamic, it will work for each specific case. Getting a dynamic solution using traditional image processing techniques to work in all situations is difficult

Comment: Can you explain how to process that image in a generic method? It is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenCV conversion, but remember to use 3 chanels, otherwise you'll get error

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```